# Specifying interactions as predictor variables in a GLMM R formula - correct method?

Tags: modeling

I am modelling insect count data as a GLMM of distance along a transect (the length of a growing tunnel (m)), temperature along the tunnel and external daily max temperature, ie in R-

---

Insect_count ~ Distance_along_tunnel_transect * temperature_along_tunnel * external_temperature * treatment + offset(log(food_resources)) + (1|row) + (1|date), family ="poisson".

---

Temperature varies along the length of the transect (ie positive linear, but variation between treatments), but also across days and over the course of a day. Insect abundance drops with increasing distance along the transect, inversely proportional to the temperature. However, insect abundance is increased with increased external temperature - which influences all temperature within the tunnels. I have data from temperature probes along the length of the transect and also data from outside the tunnels. From what I understand of this GLMM and my data, the variations in temperature between days will be accounted for by the random effect of 'date' when the transect was undertaken. I am not sure how to formulate my model to account for the effect of the external temperature on insects counts and see how the interaction between 'temperature_along_tunnel' and 'distance along tunnel' affects the insect distribution along the tunnel. My thoughts are:

---

Insect_count ~ Distance_along_tunnel_transect * external_temperature * (Distance_along_tunnel_transect:temperature_along_tunnel treatment) + offset(log(food_resources)) + (1|row) + (1|date), family ="poisson"

---

I am not sure if this is correct, of if I am better off specifying that interaction as an offset or including transect time (to account for daily fluctuations in temperature) as a random effect.

Comment: Missed a ")" in offset?

Comment: Thanks, that was just a typo

Comment: It is not an answer to your question. Based on "specifying that interaction as an offset", I think you need to learn more about the offset in Poisson regression and also am afraid if  "offset(log(food_resources)) " is correct. In Poisson regression, offset has special meaning. You can change/modify fixed effects, random effect or anything else, but you can not change offset.